# How to send data from the frontend with Vue to backend with nodeJs for the update functionality in CRUD using axios API?

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, axios

I am able to complete the CRUD operations except update, my guess is the data flow into the updateTask function is not occurring correctly, what is the correction I need to make to fix the problem?

I sent in the data in the form of id and the title to the updateTodo function but it wont work.

this code is in the front end file.

```
 updateTodo(id,title) {
      axios.put(`http://localhost:4000/todos/${id}`,{title:this.todo.title}).then(() => {
        this.getTodos();
        this.isEditing = false;
      });
    }
```

and this is the code in the backend linked with axios.

```
router.route('/:id').put((req,res)=>{
    Todo.findById(req.params.id,(err,todo)=>{
        if(!todo){
            res.send('Error fetching the todo.');
        }else{
            todo.title = req.body.title;
            todo.save()
            .then(todo=>{
                res.json({'msg':'Todo updated successfully.'});
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                res.send('the error in updating the task is ' + err);
            })


        }
    })
})
```

The update functionality is working fine with the put method in the backend (checked via postman) but not working from the frontend.

Comment: Could you expand on *"not working"* - errors? Unexpected outputs? CORS issues, by any chance?

Comment: i managed to fix the problem, i jumped the gun and posted a question. 
it was a problem how the todo data was feeding into the updateTodo function.

Comment: `code` 
    updateTodo(todo) {
      axios.put(`http://localhost:4000/todos/${todo._id}`,{title:todo.title}).then(() => {
        this.getTodos();
        this.isEditing = false;
      });
    }
I am fairly new to this site, please excuse the formatting.

Comment: Then I suggest just deleting the question.

Comment: all right, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
updateTodo(todo) {
  axios.put(`http://localhost:4000/todos/${todo._id}`,{title:todo.title}).then(() => {
    this.getTodos();
    this.isEditing = false;
  });
}
```

sent in the whole todo instead of id and title separately, my bad for not checking it before posting.